# MongoDB query _id

Tags: mongodb

So in my MongoDB test the _id field is a unique string in format of "SensorSN:YrMonthDay"

What I want to query is all data for 2016 month 3. But I can't quite get the Regex right.

So here is some sample _ids:
12345678:2016325
87654321:2016325

Basically I want to return both of the documents because they are in the month of March.

My first attempts have been similar to db.collection.find({'_id':'/:20163/'}) and so far no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: As the posted answer says, don't quote the regex, just use `{_id: /20163/}`. But I think your date format will get you in trouble. With just a single digit month (3 instead of 03), wouldn't Jan 11 and Nov 1 both be `2016111`?

Comment: That's a great point, I am going to make that change right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take off the quotes, the find is looking for a string matching exactly that instead of doing the regex search.

```
db.collection.find({ '_id': /:20163/ })
```

or

```
db.collection.find({ _id: /:20163/ })
```

both work fine for me!

Your case would only match if your sample document was:

```
{ _id: "/:20163/" }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!! Works perfectly, always seems to be something small!

Comment: Make sure you look at JohnnyHK's comment, he brought up a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes

```
db.collection.find({ _id: /:20163/ });
```

Or try using regex -

```
db.collection.find({ _id: { $regex: /:20163/ } });
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/